# How to turn my 'shopping cart' function into an object oriented program using Class() and __init__?

Tags: python, methods, python-class

```
 def userQty():
     name = input("Quantity: ")
     return name
 def userAdd():
     add = input("What would you like to add do your cart? ")
     return add
 def userInfo():
     data = {}

     while True:
         result = input(
             "Make your shopping list. Please type (Show/Add/Delete/Clear/Quit). ")

         if result.lower() == 'add':
             data[userQty()] = userAdd()
         elif result.lower() == 'show':
             print(data)

         elif result.lower() == 'delete':
             print("Still working on that, use 'clear' for now please.")
             # Could not figure out how to remove one item

         elif result.lower() == 'clear':
             dLi = input("Clear your list?: [y/n] ").lower()
             if dLi in ["y", "yes"]:
                 data = {}
                 print("Your list has been cleared.")
                 print(data)
             elif dLi in ["n", "no"]:
                 print("Action Abandoned.")
         elif result.lower() == 'quit':
             break
         else:
             print(
                 'Oops! Something went wrong. Please type "(Show/Add/Delete/Clear/Quit)"')
     print(data)
     return data

 userInfo()
```

I am fairly new to programming as a whole so I'm sorry if the code is sloppy or if I am not being specific enough?

I tried adding:

```
def __init__(self):
    return #something
```

I am lost as far as where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You could add:

```
class Somthing():
    def __init__(self):
    code
```

and add the variables to self, like this:

```
self.name = name
```

also put `(self):` in the function parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to make your different menu items methods on your object:

```
class ShoppingCart:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
    
    def add(self):
        i = input("What would you like to add to your cart? ")
        self.data[i] = input("Quantity: ")

    def clear(self):
        if input("Clear your list? [y/n] ").lower().startswith("y"):
            self.data = {}
            print("Your list has been cleared.")
        else:
            print("Action abandoned.")

    def delete(self):
        print("Still working on that, use 'clear' for now please.")

    def menu_loop(self):
        while True:
            i = input(
                "Make your shopping list. "
                "Please type (Show/Add/Delete/Clear/Quit). "
            ).lower()
            if i == "quit":
                break
            try:
                getattr(self, i)()
            except AttributeError:
                print(
                    'Oops! Something went wrong. '
                    'Please type "(Show/Add/Delete/Clear/Quit)"'
                )


cart = ShoppingCart()
cart.menu_loop()
print(cart.data)
```